# How to merge two data table such as a join works on two table and without getting columns duplicated

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, linq

I want to merge two datatable. This merge should be like it's a join on these two datatable where three columns value should match in both the tables.

Both table may contain same column name but the output should only come one column, I mean it should not get duplicated.

I have tried something using linq

```
var nQuery = from dstbl in dsNew.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             join dttbl in tempDt.AsEnumerable()
             on new
             {
                F1 = dstbl.Field<object>("Resource Name"),
                F2 = dstbl.Field<object>("Level"),
                F3 = dstbl.Field<object>("Location")
             }
             equals new
             {
                F1 = dttbl.Field<object>("Resource Name"),
                F2 = dttbl.Field<object>("Level"),
                F3 = dttbl.Field<object>("Location")
             }
             select new { dstbl, dttbl };
```

I don't know how to use the nQuery after execution of this statement.

Can you please tell me something so that this statemnt gives me the exact table structure instead of annonymous object without duplicate column if both datatable contain the same column.

Or anything other way like using Merge() if you can suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the Linq Union operator should work for this.

Comment: union is giving me the cross product of the tables without duplicate columns but giving m*n rows

Comment: only those rows should be ouput if tbl1.c1=tbl2.c1 and tbl1.c2=tbl.c2